# Failed to Connect to server [localhost:5000] on first connect

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect my node app with mongodb. It worked before but now it shows "Failed to connect to server [localhost:5000] on first connect.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// connection to the db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:5000/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true });
 const DB = mongoose.connection;
DB.once('open', () => console.log("We are connected to the database"));
DB.on('error', () => console.log("Error connecting to the databse"));
```

## And when I run the server, it shows this message..

Error connecting to the databse
(node:11156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to cononnect [[object Object]]

```
    at Pool.<anonymous> (E:\projects\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topo
    at Pool.emit (events.js:189:13)

   at connect (E:\projects\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\po

    at callback (E:\projects\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\c

   at runCommand (E:\projects\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection

   at Connection.errorHandler (E:\projects\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lrojects\project\node_modules\mongodb:277:13)-core\lib\connection\connect.js:321:9:13)5)    
                          ts\project\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\co
   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js):277:13)                            :284:12)
   at Conn
```

ection.emit (events.js:18dable.js:265:11)9:13)                               _readable.js:220:10)

```
   at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\projec(internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)ts\project\node_modules\mongodb-coreonWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. Thi\lib\connection\connection.js:498:20tch block, or by rejecting a promise which )
at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13rning: Unhandled promise rejections are dep)                                    the Node.js process with a non-zero exit c

at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread]
```

(internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)

(node:11156) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)(node:11156) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejectionsthat are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Hi, silly question but is your mongodb instance running on port 5000? The most common case is to run on port 27017.

Comment: my node app is running on port 5000

Comment: Yeah, i get that... but your mongodb must be running on a different port. Try changing to ```mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname', { useNewUrlParser: true });```